# How to change fragment after a certain time?

Tags: android, kotlin

My application consists of 3 main screens (fragments that switch between themselves bottom navigation).
Launching the app opens the Home screen (shown in code)
The question is the following. I want to add a welcome snippet that will run the very first one, where I'll make an animation and write something like "Hi, I'm an application!".
How can I make this fragment run first, and most importantly, how can I set it a time, for example 3 seconds, after which the Home fragment will start (that is, it will go to the fragment that I have right now when I start the application)?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    var binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    replaceFragment(HomeFragment())

    binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.home -> {
                replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
                true
            }
            R.id.profile -> {
                replaceFragment(ProfileFragment())
                true
            }
            R.id.settings -> {
                replaceFragment(SettingsFragment())
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
}

private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

}

Comment: Have you looked into `Handler().postDelayed()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code change time (3000, 1000) according to your requeirment

```
    var countDownTimer =  object : CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
               override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                }
    
              override  fun onFinish() {
                   //Replace fragment method here 
                }
            }.start()
```